# How to disable xampp from accessing the internet, but enable localhost access by browser

Tags: firefox, xampp

I'm using xampp and had a local installation of a site script in my PC. I want to use Mozilla Firefox browser to see the front-end of the site I'm trying to code, but also want the xampp to not communicate online. Are there any ways to do it without unplugging my ethernet cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing a [similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/577720/block-network-access-to-local-development-server) on SuperUser, you could use your firewall to block access.

The poster in that question used a third-party program called Comodo, however it would be easy to convert this over to whatever firewall you have. You just want to block `{your path to}\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe` from connecting to the internet.

If you aren't sure how to do this then a quick Google search will show you how.

Comment: Thank you. that did the trick. I just made a rule on firewall that blocked the oubound connection of httpd.exe just as you said. Thanks mate, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For block access to your Xampp web server just click con config>Apache (httpd.conf)

[image: Xammp Options]

And edit changing the line Listen to:

```
 Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

You can add a rule to your firewall too, but if Apache, don't serve to anyone else 127.0.0.1, there is no chance for reach your xampp server.

For allow others access to your web server :

```
 Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```