# XAMPP security: protect access from internet

Tags: security, xampp

Probably this question was already asked, but I would appreciate a confirmation that I'm doing things right.

I run XAMPP 5.6 and all pcs connected to wifi are trusted. I'm behind a router and no virtual server or port forwarding are enabled.

(On this version of XAMPP the security.php page is gone.)

I would like that XAMPP allow access to htdocs folder (mysites) ONLY from pcs connected to my wifi, and stay locked from Internet (rejecting access to htdocs and all xampp setting folder and files).

QUESTION 1:

1) if I do nothing (not even add a password to root), is XAMPP (settings folder and/or my sites in htdocs folder) open to internet or just to my local wifi pcs?

QUESTION 2:
Adding this to httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all

  Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost 192.xxx.xxx
</Directory>
```

will reinforce security allowing only connection from specified local ips (and reject ANY connections from internet)?

As a test, I did try the following addresses (from another internet connection):

1) my-isp-ip/routerip/mysite

2) my-isp-ip:80/routerip/mysite

and the pages just did not load.

Is it a good test?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I too am trying to figure out whether XAMPP poses a huge security risk to my PC.

Comment: I'm sorry, but nobody seems to be interested in answering this question... sorry I can't help

Comment: The issue was dealt with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646897/how-to-disable-xampp-from-accessing-the-internet-but-enable-localhost-access-by), the main advice being to set your firewall to prevent the XAMPP apps (e.g. Apache) from accessing the internet.